# Get source files from an interface library

Tags: cmake

I have a header only library I want to write a CMake file for, to be used in other projects. To do this I need to declare the library an interface target. The header files are then added by CMakeList.txt files in subfolders.

Now I want to get the list of source files to run clang-format on them. But `get_target_property` does not work on interface targets. Is there any way to extract the sources (or headers) from an interface target?

This is the code I have at the moment (not working)

```
make_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(foo
  LANGUAGES CXX
  VERSION 1.0.0)

add_library(bar INTERFACE)

# add header files in sub folders with
target_sources(bar INTERFACE
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/header.h"
    )

# this gives the error
get_target_property(MY_SOURCES bar SOURCES)
```

The error message

```
INTERFACE_LIBRARY targets may only have whitelisted properties.  The
property "SOURCES" is not allowed.
```

I tried to link the interface target into a real target and get the sources that way, but I only got the sources added directly to the second target, not the sources from the interface target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your target is declared as `INTERFACE`, the [`target_sources()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_sources.html#command:target_sources) command populates the [`INTERFACE_SOURCES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_SOURCES.html) property of the target, not `SOURCES`. From the docs:

> The `INTERFACE`, `PUBLIC` and `PRIVATE` keywords are required to specify the scope of the following arguments. `PRIVATE` and `PUBLIC` items will populate the `SOURCES` property of `<target>`. `PUBLIC` and `INTERFACE` items will populate the `INTERFACE_SOURCES` property of `<target>`.

Try grabbing the `INTERFACE_SOURCES` property instead:

```
add_library(bar INTERFACE)

# add header files in sub folders with
target_sources(bar INTERFACE
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/header.h"
    )

# this gives the error
get_target_property(MY_SOURCES bar INTERFACE_SOURCES)
```